# raspberrypi email notifier - py command not found

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Just bought a raspberry pi and i'm trying to get my first project up and running, but linux keeps saying that it can't find my command, even though it's there. I'm not positive, because I'm new to this, but I believe the problem is coming from **[here](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-e-mail-notifier-using-leds/python-script)**. I've watched tutorials on YouTube as well, but nobody else runs into this problem. Here's my output...

I'm new to the Linux way of things as well..

[image]

When I enter `sudo python ./raspi-email.py` I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./raspi-gmail.py", line 21, in <module>
    newmails = int(feedparser.parse("https://" + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD +"@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]["fullcount"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/feedparser.py", line 375, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'fullcount'
```

Comment: what is the output of `/usr/bin/env python` ?

Comment: Try `sudo /full/path/to/raspi-gmail.py`

Comment: @g4ur4v the weird thing is that i get a `could not be found` message when i navigate to it. when i go to `/usr/bin` it shows up, but it won't let me change directories to it.

Comment: You can try `sudo python ./raspi-gmail.py`

Comment: just tried it, but got an error, i updated my question for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you file has execute permissions.
Use `chmod` command to give execute permissions to your file.
`chmod +x raspi-gmail.py`

```
g4ur4v@g4ur4v:~$ cat ./r.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'hii'    

g4ur4v@g4ur4v:~$ sudo ./r.py
sudo: ./r.py: command not found

g4ur4v@g4ur4v:~$ sudo /home/g4ur4v/Desktop/junk/r.py
sudo: /home/g4ur4v/Desktop/junk/r.py: command not found

g4ur4v@g4ur4v:~$ pwd
/home/g4ur4v/Desktop/junk

g4ur4v@g4ur4v:~$ ll /home/g4ur4v/Desktop/junk/r.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g4ur4v g4ur4v 33 Sep 22 03:29 /home/g4ur4v/Desktop/junk/r.py

g4ur4v@g4ur4v:~$ chmod +x /home/g4ur4v/Desktop/junk/r.py

g4ur4v@g4ur4v:~$ sudo /home/g4ur4v/Desktop/junk/r.py
hii

g4ur4v@g4ur4v:~$ sudo ./r.py
hii
```

Comment: From what I know, the shell looks for the executable file in the paths specified in `${PATH}` variable, if the file is in those path and it doesn't have execute permissions it returns `command not found`.

Comment: Just did this and I got the same error as when I ran `sudo python ./raspi-gmail.py`

Comment: technically, this answer is not the end result, but it did lead me to the answer, which can be found below. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod u+x raspi-gmail.py      // use 'x' in small not in caps
this one 
sudo ./raspi-gmail.py

or try 
sudo python raspi-gmail.py
```

Comment: Interesting, here's what it gave me...

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raspi-gmail.py", line 16, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(GREEN_LED, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out - gmail has a new two factor authentication requirement, so i had to generate a password specific to this app. I located the answer [here](http://adafruit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=39442).